# Flow Generator type is not being recognized by eslint

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator, eslint, flowtype

I'm using eslint with flowtype. It was working perfectly until I decided to use es6 generators. When I export a generator, I need to specify the return type but eslint is not recognizing the Generator type.

```
export function *gen2(): Generator {
  yield 'test';
}
```

Eslint shows this error: `'Generator' is not defined.` but flow works perfectly.

Anyone has any idea on how to make eslint recognize the Generator type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no global `Generator` constructor in JS, so ESLint will see that as unknown. You'll need to add it to your `.eslintrc` as a global, e.g.

```
{
  "rules": {},
  "globals": {
    "Generator": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use babel-eslint + https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype + **https://github.com/zertosh/eslint-plugin-flow-vars**